# Replace cells in one cell variable in Matlab

Tags: matlab, variables, replace, cell

I have one variable (1X30 cell) and I want to replace cells 21 through 30 with cells 21 through 30 from another variable (also 1X30 cell). Can someone help?

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: OriginalCell(21:30) = NewCell(21:30)?

Comment: Internet (Including S.O.) is full of solutions on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the documentation on [cells](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html) and on [indexing](http://se.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html). This is quite a simple task:

```
C1(21:end) = C2(21:end)
```

or

```
C1(21:30) = C2(21:30)
```